# How to test functions used in a stateless component that's defined outside of the component's scope in Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to write a test for the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import Popup from 'some-library'

const popupConfig = {
  home: {
    popupValue: 'Hello World',
    popupValue: 'action',
    popupMessage: 'Get Started'
  },
  settings: {
    popupValue: 'Hello World',
    popupValue: 'action',
    popupMessage: 'Get Started'
  }
}

const closePopup = () => {
  Popup.closePopup()
}

const toggleNewPopup = () => {
  Popup.togglePopup('some-popup')
}

const GetStartedPopup = ({ moduleName }) => {
  if (!Object.keys(popupConfig).includes(moduleName)) return null
  const {
    popupValue = 'Hi there!',
    popupStyle = 'warning',
    popupMessage = 'Get Started',
    popupBtnFunction = toggleNewPopup
  } = popupConfig[moduleName]

  return (
    <Popup
      popupValue={popupValue}
      popupStyle={popupStyle}
      popupBtnValue={popupMessage}
      popupBtnStyle="neutral"
      popupBtnFunction={popupBtnFunction}
      xPopup={closePopup}
    />
  )
}

export default GetStartedPopup
```

The objective of the test is to make sure that the `closePopup` and `toggleNewPopup` functions are called. I'm doing the following to do that for the `closePopup function`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { Popup } from 'some-library'
import GetStartedPopup from 'widgets/getStartedPopup'

describe('<GetStartedPopup/>', () => {
    let wrapper
    let props
    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
            page: 'home'
        }
        wrapper  = mount(<GetStartedPopup {...props}/>)
    })

    it('should render the component without crashing', () => {
        expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
    })

    it('should call closePopup', () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'closePopup');
        wrapper.instance().closePopup();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.unmount()
    })
})
```

I went through the docs for `spyOn` and other SO threads that tackle issues like this but couldn't resolve how to test the `closePopup` and `toggleNewPopup` functions for my case here. When I run the test case written above I get this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'closePopup' of null`. What would be the correct way to write the test to make sure that the two functions are called?

Comment: Why are you testing parts of `GetStartedPopup` that aren't really part of it? You can't spy on, or invoke, a function that isn't part of the instance object. Have you tried moving your handlers into your functional component?

Comment: yes I did. Still get the same error because `wrapper.instance()` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Funny that I ran into this myself at work in regards to `wrapper.instance()` [doc](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html#props--object)

> To return the props for the entire React component, use wrapper.instance().props. This is valid for stateful or stateless components in React 15.. But, wrapper.instance() will return null for stateless React component in React 16., so wrapper.instance().props will cause an error in this case.

As for the 3rd party library. You should be mocking any collaborators that your component uses.

```
import { Popup } from 'some-library';
describe('<GetStartedPopup />', () => {
  let wrapper;

  jest.mock('some-library', () => {
    Popup: jest.fn(),
  });

  const initialProps = {
    page: 'home'
  };

  const getStartedPopup = () => {
    return mount(<GetStartedPopup {...initialProps});
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    Popup.mockClear()
    wrapper = getStartedPopup();
  };

  it('should call closePopup', () => {
    expect(Popup.closePopup()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
  ...
});
```